# How can a delegate in a sound class cause a change of a button image in a controller class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to create a button that plays a sound and after the completion of the sound to change the button's image. I'm having difficulties to sync between the sound and the image change.

I have a controller class that upon button pressed calls a sound class. 
The sound class plays an audio file (using AVAudioPlayer) and after completion calls the delegate audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying. This delegate should change the image, but the sound delegate is located in a sound class and the button's properties are located in the controller class so the delegate cannot communicate with the button.

(I thought about sending a pointer to the button to the sound class, or I could use the NSNotificationCenter, but I'm really not sure)

The question is how can the delegate cause the image change of the UIButton?

Here's some code:

```
//  try1ViewController.h

@class AVSnd;

@interface try1ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>{
    AVSnd *mAvs1;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVSnd *mAvs1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;

@end





// try1ViewController.m

- (IBAction)Button2Pressed:(id)sender 
{
//...
self.mAvs1 = [[AVSnd alloc] initWithCafFile:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: audioX2, audioY1, nil ]];
//...
[myButton2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:image1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//...
}




//  AVSnd.h

@interface AVSnd : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
AVAudioPlayer *mSoundPlayer;
NSArray* fileNameQueue;
int index;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *mSoundPlayer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* fileNameQueue;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int index; 


-(id)initWithCafFile: (NSArray*)queue;
-(void)playWithNum: (int) num;
-(void)fadeOut;
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)mSoundPlayer successfully:(BOOL)flag;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your  **sound** class **AVAudioPlayer** delegate as **controller** class object

Implement the **audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying** in controller class.

Then the delegate will trigger in controller class. You can change it the properties easily.

**Note**: Don't create a new **controller class object** inside the **sound class** . You can pass it as per your wish.

Comment: Can you take a look at the code I posted and be more specific in how would the delegate trigger the controller class? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a protocol and a delegate that sends a message from AVSnd to the viewController. 
Then, the viewController is able to load a method associated with his class, based on the information received from AVSnd.